# Facebook login for companies

Tags: facebook, authentication, twitter, user-accounts

My website has accounts that are often accessed by multiple users. For example, a company might create an account under a generic company email address, and have different interns, etc update it.

We also have normal users that are the only people accessing their account.

We know we could make registering / signing in so much easier and more effective by utilizing various third party services like Facebook, Twitter, OpenID, etc, but we can't think of how to handle those services when multiple people want to create / sign into a single account.

How do we know which users authenticated with FB/Twitter should be allowed to access the company account on our website?

Facebook doesn't let you sign in as a Page yet, right?

Answer (score 1):

Technically, no you can not log in as a page.  But, once you get an install from a user, you can easily tell which page they are administrators of.  If you create your company organizational unit around the entity of a page (or allow users to do this) then you could allow your users to log in with their Facebook accounts and once you have their Facebook session, you can access the `/me/accounts` graph endpoint and look at the pages they're administrators of and cross reference that with your company->Facebook Page definitions.

You could allow Facebook Page Administrators to invite users who do not have access to their Facebook Page.  Once the lesser-privileged (intern) user gets to their invite URL endpoint, they could click a Facebook connect button to link their FB account with the Company/Page that the Administrator invited them to.  This way, the Administrator wouldn't have to add a bunch of users to their Facebook Page as Administrators (thereby keeping their page more secure).

Comment: To get /me/accounts you have to get the manage_pages permission, and giving that permission to an online service is scary for most users. I doubt they would give access to their company facebook page, and would have to create new fake page just for this service, which is against the facebook TOS.

Comment: Danny, that's a good point...it does seem a little scary. Most of our users are very shy about the internet as well. Our site is often their first attempt or entry (given our specific demographic).

Comment: The other thing is that we've attempted something like this before, and getting people to understand the connection of being a FB admin on their page in correlation to using our site as their company is really hard.

Comment: @DannyKK - that is incorrect.  You can access `/me/accounts` without the manage-pages permission.  In fact, you do not need any special permissions beyond a standard install to access this endpoint.

Comment: @johnnietheblack if your users are "shy about the internet" and it's hard for them to understand the link between Facebook and your application - then it might not be a good idea to offer to use Facebook as their primary method of logging in.  Just a thought.

Comment: @JimR - Could you please explain what do you mean by 'standard install'/? I hope facebook doesn't permit just anyone to get tokens for all your pages without at least some basic security.

Comment: @DannyKK - just a vanilla install, no extra permissions required.  You don't get access tokens to the pages with this kind of an install, but you do get a list of all the 'accounts' the user has access to (basically, all the apps/pages they're admins of)

Comment: @JimR - Thank you for the info, it's counter intuitive to the new facebook privacy policy, so I've never thought to try, and of course it isn't mentioned in the documentation. Nice catch.

Comment: @DannyKK - not mentioned in the Facebook docs? noo, you don't say...that never happens! `</scarcasm>` lol!

Answer (score 1):

You can let the users log in with their normal company account, and then give them a facebook Connect button. The only important thing you need to keep for facebook connect is their facebook id. I would add a new table, or a new entry in the users table with all the ids that have connected to that account. There would be no difference between single user and multiple user accounts, only in the number of ids connected to that account.

I use a sql table with two values, user_id and remote_id, and every time a user connects you add an entry. The same can be done with other open ids and twitter, the same able can be used.